# What does `Sizzle.tokenize` do

Tags: javascript, jquery, tokenize, sizzle

`Sizzle.tokenize` is undocumented and there is no comments in the source. What does it do?

[The code](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L1538-L1603)

Comment: Can you elaborate? give some examples what it does and how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It split the string css selector. 
E

> Example: "div > button.btn", if you use this string to tokenize,
>   Sizzle.tokenize returns an array with arrays as item and within that
>   array item there is an object that has property type and value. In
>   example above the results will be [[{type: "tag",value: "div"},{type:
>   ">",value: " > "},{type: "tag",value: "button"},{type: "class",value:
>   "btn"}]].

If you use another selector with comma it adds new array inside the parent array.